# how to present .mat data in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I imported my data from excel to matlab and saved it as 't.mat'.I used function:

```
load('t.mat')
open('t.mat') 
ans =
ndata: [62x8 double]
text: {63x9 cell}
alldata: {63x9 cell}
```

but it did not show the data.I want to see the column 5 of the data an plot it,so i wrote :

```
x=t.mat(:,5) 
plot(x)
```

the error was : 
??? Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.

please help me to present the data and plot it.
thanks

Comment: Which data do you want to see and plot? `load` loads the variables into the same names as they were when you saved the `.mat` file - check your workspace.

Comment: i want to see the data in details. for example all rows and columns with numbers,but it does not show me.and i want to plot data in column 5. is there any function or syntax to present and show the numbers of t.mat?

Comment: @ghazal so did any answer help you solve your problem? If so please accept one of them. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

't.mat' is just the name of the file where your data is stored. When you load a file, it loads the content into your workspace with the saved variable names, here *ndata*, *text* and *alldata*.

You then need to call the variables themselves to access the data:

```
load('t.mat')
x = ndata(:,5);
plot(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can load your data into a structure and easily access them:

```
DataStruct = load('t.mat');

A = DataStruct.alldata; % Assign a variable to alldata. 

plot(A{:,5});
```

Following on @Darthbit's comment, once you load the .mat file ,variables are available in the workspace, so you could use something like this:

```
load('t.mat');
plot(alldata{:,5})
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Matlab in a while but I'm pretty sure you can't just say:

```
x=t.mat(:,5)
```

I think you have to store the t.mat into something.  Here's a page that might be helpful:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html#btm3ohm-1